# C++ define a structure with variable elements in it

Tags: c++

So basically im a student and im trying to make database system dumping all the data into text files and reading from them as a learning exercise.

What I realised is that if im reading the structre of a table from a text file then I'd need a way to define a data structure which will be created  without me knowing what it's contents ever are.

I just started with C++ in highschool, and am only allowed to use everything inside the Cx11 standard.Is this possible to implement?

I know  a little about templates but the problem still remains I don't know  how many datatypes will be inside my structure.

So equivalently  this problem can be put as reading the info from the console and then making the structure:

```
string type;
vector < pair <string,string> > Input;
string name;

while(true)
{
    cin >> type;
    cin >> name;



    if( type == "end")
        break;
Input.push_back(make_pair(type,name));


}

struct user_created
{
    //Define what they wanted to create in here.

};
```

Comment: If you need a generic structure, maybe you need a base class and then differentiate for map, list or scalar type substructures. This is how things like a generic JSON library does it.

Comment: If you don't need to know what the contents of the structure are then you don't need a structure. If you need to programmatically access the contents of the structures you read, there is no way in the language to populate a 'struct' which could then be used in the normal fashion. You need some degree of reflection, which is not currently supported in the standard.